# Jenkins http plugin to upload file using rest

Tags: rest, jenkins, jenkins-pipeline

I am trying to upload a file to a rest server from jenkins using http plugin. I have a jenkins pipelie where a step involves loading a file(type formData)
 to a server using rest.

the server side method uses two parameters:

```
(@FormDataParam("file") InputStream file, @FormDataParam("fileName") String fileName)
```

I am using the below method

```
def filename = "${WORKSPACE}/Test.txt"
data="""{ \"fileName\" : \"Test.txt\" }"""
resp3 = httpRequest  consoleLogResponseBody: true,url: "http://<url>",contentType:'APPLICATION_OCTETSTREAM',customHeaders:[[name:'Authorization', value:"Basic ${auth}"]],httpMode: 'POST',multipartName: 'Test.txt',uploadFile: "${filename}",requestBody:data,validResponseCodes: '200'
```

but when I run the status code is 400 and in the server logs  the message is that no filestream and no filename is received i.e not able to get both the arguments.

Please let me know where it is getting wrong

Regards

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since I was running on windows so bat + curl worked for me .With this workaround I was able to transfer files using jenkins and rest
However using httpRequest from jenkins inbuild library is still not working.

Answer (score 0):

You can try using `curl` instead of built-in Jenkins methods:

```
curl -XPOST http://<url> -H 'Content-Type: application/octet-stream' -H 'Authorization: Basic ${auth}'  --data-binary '{\"fileName\" : \"Test.txt\" }'
```

You can debug it first from within shell. Once it's working, wrap it in `sh` directive:

```
sh "curl ..."
```

Comment: Hi I am using the syntax def response = sh(script: curl -X POST --insecure --request '<url>' --header 'Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded' --header 'Authorization: Basic ${auth}' --form 'file: @${filename}' --form 'fileName:${fname}', returnStdout: true)  but not succeeding

Comment: Its giving syntax error, can you help me where am I getting wrong, I need to provide the full path as variable as it may change with subsequent run

Comment: I modified the Url : def response = sh(script: curl -XPOST --insecure --user "user:ppass" "<url>" --header "Content-Type: multipart/form-data" --form "file=@${filename}" --form "fileName=${fname}", returnStdout: true)

Comment: the curl is working outside jenkins : curl -XPOST --insecure --user "user:ppass" "<url>" --header "Content-Type: multipart/form-data" --form "file=@${filename}" --form "fileName=${fname}" , but inside jenkins it is failing

Comment: solved it , I was running in windows , used bat instead of sh and it worked